# Обработка Ajax-запроса без echo

Tags: ajax, yii

Использую Ajax-запрос:

```
$.get('/site/index', { type: 'delete' });
```

Отсылаю запрос на сервер, где обрабатываю его в PHP:

```
public function actionIndex($data = null, $type = null)
{ 
  // некие действия с данными 
}
```

Интересно то, что запрос отрабатывает только если сделать `echo`:

```
public function actionIndex($data = null, $type = null)
{ 
    echo "ok";
    // некие действия с данными 
}
```

То есть если отдаю данные в ответ, то остальной код отрабатывает.

Почему так происходит?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{type:'delete'}
```

это в формате Json

```
($data = null, $type = null)
```

а эти принимают GET запросы.

так что у вас путаница с get запросом. протестируйте

```
$.get('/site/index?type=delete');
```